# Is this inequality known, true involving products of quadratic expressions $(x_p^2+bx_p+c)$?

Tags: inequality

Is this inequality true? If so, what is its name and how to get it?

For $x_p\gt0$, $\prod\limits_{p=1}^{n}x_p=1$, and $b^2-4c\lt0$.
$$
\prod_{p=1}^{n}\left(x_p^2+bx_p+c\right)\leqslant\sum_{p=1}^{n}\left(x_p^2\prod_{q=1,q\neq p}^{n}\left(x_q^2+bx_q+c\right)\right)\Large{?}
$$

Comment: did not make the calculations but i think it holds, in order to prove it, use the given ineq. and add terms and variations of the sequence product and at the last step use sth like [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(might be wrong) This doesn't seem true to me. Take $x_i = 1$, then we want to show that

$$ ( 1 + b + c)^n \leq n ( 1 + b + c)^{n-1}$$

Clearly, this is not true for a large enough $c$.